# users.users.<name>.packages vs home-manager packages

Tags: nix, home-manager

Is there any practical difference between

```
users.users.default.packages = [
  pkgs.foo
];
```

and

```
home-manager = {
  users.default = {
    config,
    pkgs,
    nixpkgs,
    lib,
    specialArgs,
    options,
    modulesPath,
    nixosConfig,
    osConfig,
  }: {
    home = {
      packages = [
        pkgs.foo
      ];
    };

  };
  useGlobalPkgs = true;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former is configured by the system owner and the latter by the user. The former thus requires root privileges. Other than that, there is no difference.

Comment: As [mentioned by tejing](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/users-users-name-packages-vs-home-manager-packages/22240/4), there are some practical differences with `$PATH` priority and package conflicts.